# Laravel Routing: How to route when using URL query string?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, routes

I have a route - let's call it ***stats***. Here is what my routing currently looks like:

```
Route::get('stats', 'StatsController@index');
Route::get('stats/{query}', 'StatsController@store');
```

My goal is to show stat data if someone visits ***/stats*** and to store stat data if someone visits a URL similar to ***/stats?name=John&device=Android***.

How would I then route if there is a query string attached to my namespace ***stats***?

Something like this?

```
Route::get('stats/?name=*&device=*', 'StatsController@store');
```

Comment: Check if Input is empty

Answer (score 6, accepted):

routes.php

```
Route::get('stats', 'StatsController@index');
```

StatsController

```
public function index()
{
    if(Input::has('name') and Input::has('device')))
        return $this->store();

    // Show stat ...
}

public function store()
{
    $input = Input::only('name', 'device');

    // Store stat ...
}
```

although it seems a pefect scenario for a RESTFUL controller. Whoever is sending the input should do it with a POST request